# erlang logger does not show progress reports

Tags: logging, erlang, elixir, ejabberd, erlang-otp

iam new in logging i tried the erlang new logger API in erlang/OTP 21 so i have write a simple code to create a custom handler :

```
-module(loggertest).
-export([start/0,doError/2]).
%%%%%%
start() ->
HandlerFile="/Erlang/informations.log",
HandlerConfig=# {max_no_bytes=>10*1024*1024,
 max_no_files=>1,
 file=>HandlerFile},
FormatConfig=#{single_line=>false,
               legacy_header=>true},
TheHandler=#{level=>info,
             config=>HandlerConfig,
             formatter=> {logger_formatter,FormatConfig}},
logger:set_handler_config(default,level,error),
logger:set_primary_config(level,info),
logger:add_handler(the_handler,logger_std_h,TheHandler).
%%%%%%
doError(X,Y) ->
logger:error(#{x=X,y=Y}).
```

so i compile it and call

```
loggertest:start().
loggertest:doError(4,5).
```

i checked the "informations.log" file and i found just the error report

```
x=4
y=5
```

and there is any progress reports, and when remove

```
logger:set_handler_config(default,level,error)
```

i have the progress reports in the terminal so i have nothing understand: the call to the `logger:set_handler_config/3` will stop the default logger to catch events superior than error events so the progress reports (info events) will never handled by the default logger who will put them at the standard I/O after formatting, and here i expected that these reports will be handled by TheHandler because it have info level but nothing of that happened, why ?

Comment: i add this ```doInfo(X,Y) ->logger:info(#{x=X,y=Y}).``` and the info report found in the handler file so where is the problem with progress reports ? iam using Erlang/OTP 23